# how to load data in splash screen and then pass it into fragment viewmodel in android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, splash-screen, android-livedata

I'm creating a translation app, and it needs to download the language list every time the app is opened. I want to create a splash screen, load the data in the splash screen activity, and then pass it into my fragment viewmodel.

I think using the same viewmodel between the splash screen activity and the activity that holds the fragment is one way, but it's not the best way because each viewmodel should belong to one view.

Another way is to pass data to the fragment and then pass it to the viewmodel using a constructor but i think it is the bad way also.

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you think passing data from one `Activity` to other and then pre-loading it in `ViewModel` via `constructor` is a bad idea ?

If you want to persist data for the session, then you could save the data inside a variable in `Application` and access it across `fragments` and preload it into `ViewModel`.

If you want to persist data permanently, then you could write it to a local db from splash screen and load it into `ViewModel` from db.

Otherwise unless you have very large amount of `data` which you think could overflow the `bundle` size, I do not see any problem in passing the data between two screens and would definitely is the best way to transfer data without persisting it.

Comment: I think pre-loading data in ViewModel via constructors is a bad idea because data in ViewModel should be handled by itself, not the fragment. And I don't want to write my data to a local database because this data is obtained from an API and it could be changed by the API owner. Therefore, I believe it is better to load it from the API every time the app is opened